# Do you need to change the <a> tag ID attribute if using an external Stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a css aligned link within a pre-exsisting div, which should serve to act as a hotspot of sorts, however the page seems to render and that link is not visible (because it appears above the popup box) and it's size is 0px X 0px even though I am attempting to define it otherwise in the CSS Stylesheet. The Tutorial i used (I'm not a frontend developer, and after this brief encounter *stay away*) uses an inline stylesheet rather than external that we have for our setup (Lots of CSS relating to other things on the page). Do i need to format the `<a>` tags differently if i use an external CSS stylesheet?

My code:

```
<div id="KitchenOverlay" style="height: 310px; width: 267px;">
        <a id="closePopup" href="#"></a>
        <p>The background of this box is an image.</p>
</div>
```

The text does display, but not the rectangle.

Kitchen Overlay:

```
#KitchenOverlay 
{
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    top: 258px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-image: url(../images/Popup.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

(Like I say, not a UI developer so I might have used the ./#'s incorrectly)

ClosePopup: < This is the rectangle that won't display correctly.

```
#closePopup 
{
position: absolute; 
top: 40px; 
left: 20px; 
width: 83px; 
height: 83px; 
background-color: transparent; 
border: 1px solid yellow; 
}
```

Let me know if you need to see more.

Comment: `.KitchenOverlay` <-- this targets a class. you need `#KitchenOverlay`

Comment: I have changed the KitchenOverlay to have a '#' leading it, but that overlay displayed fine anyway, its the closePopup rectangle which doesn't.

Also, can't do a JSFiddle as the page contains a lot of other content that is proprietry/unrelated.

Comment: Is this how it all the code related to these elements:  http://jsfiddle.net/D5XQ5/?  Not related, but you're missing the non-prefixed border-radius property (which should be after all the prefixed versions).

Comment: For the most part yes, I also have a Javascript function related to it, which i have added. I can't post the whole page as some elements are proprietry.

Comment: Can you provide the JS as well?  You can use placeholder services for the images (see http://placehold.it/, http://placekitten.com/, etc)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D5XQ5/2/ apologies, i thought update updated the original jsfiddle.

Comment: The link appears to be visible to me once the parent element is revealed:  http://jsfiddle.net/D5XQ5/3/.  Is there a particular browser it isn't working in?

Comment: I worked out the issue, for some reason my CSS file was being overriden by a version on our network, Fixed it now Thanks for the help all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're problem is in your definitions.  In your HTML you are using the ID `#KitchenOverlay`

Your CSS is using `.KitchenOverlay` which targets a class.

**You have two options:**

Change `.KitchenOverlay` to `#KitchenOverlay` in your CSS.

**OR**

Change...

`<div id="KitchenOverlay" style="height: 310px; width: 267px;">`

to...

```
<div class="KitchenOverlay" style="height: 310px; width: 267px;">
```

***Edit for your reply:***

Try changing #closePopup to a class.  So `class="closePopup"` in **HTML**

Then target your  tag like this in **CSS**...

```
#KitchenOverlay .closePopup {
***STYLES***
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
#closePopup 
{
position: absolute !important; 
top: 40px !important; 
left: 20px !important; 
width: 83px !important; 
height: 83px !important; 
background-color: transparent !important; 
border: 1px solid yellow !important; 
}
```

Comment: I have changed the KitchenOverlay to have a # Preceeding it, howver that overlay was displaying correctly as it was anyway. It's the closePopup rectangle that won't display correctly.

Comment: Your additional part, I have done that, but no change in the end result, When i inspect the element in chrome and find said `<a>` tags It displays in the Chrome inspection Rollover `a#closePopup 0px x 0px` which isn't the dimensions I specified.

Comment: Can you provide a live link or try this in a JSFiddle?  It sounds like something is overwriting some of your styles, the question is where so we can know what we need to do to prevent it.

Comment: The images used are proprietry so I cannot share those, However I can give you all the code if helpful, but obviously the image maps won't work properly because of the fact you don't have the images.

Comment: Without being able to see a live view in which I can use Chrome developer tools I can't find where the issue is.  All I can suggest is to use chrome developer tools (F12) or Firebug for firefox and see if you can find the rule that is over-writing your styles.  Once you find that line you can either adjust your selectors to overwrite it.

Another possible solution would be to add !important to your rules that are being overwritten.  See my edit for an example of that.

Comment: I have a javascript function too which is used to display the KitchenOverlay in the firstplace (it's part of an image map, and the JS function is called by the OnClick event of one of the map areas) I've added it to a JSFiddle that Cinnamon created http://jsfiddle.net/D5XQ5/, I'll keep looking to see if any inherited rules are passed down.